# Ruby on Rails. Store variables in text field DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How I can store ruby string with variables in DB?
For example I have model **Stack** and attribute **welcome_message**.
I want store in welcome_message next string - "Hi, #{user}. How do you do?"
Then I make:

```
user = "artem"
p stack.welcome_message
```

and got-

> "Hi, \#{user}. How do you do?"

I can't fixate it in view, because I want change position varibles in field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

store you welcome message like this

```
Hi, <user>. How do you do?
```

and then, while displaying,

```
user = "artem"
p stack.welcome_message.gsub('<user>', user)
```

Its like adding a placeholder for user name.

Comment: Why not `%{user}` and `String#%`?